# Calculate the number of working days between two dates

Tags: javascript, datetime

I want to calculate dates that start from the 1st of January and contain only working days (Monday—Friday). How do I do that?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We will expect you to show us what you've tried already so that we can suggest improvements; we will not provide a complete solution for you without any work on your own. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I do not know how to write it, if i know it i do not asq question, all what i have now is  this http://jsbin.com/kecesi/3/edit?js,output